# What is a $R$ adic completion of $R$?

Tags: ring-theory, formal-completions

Let $R$ be a ring.
$R$ is an ideal of $R$, then,
what is the completion of $R$ with respect to ideal $R$?

I know completion by trivial ideal $0$ is a ring itself.
Is the result 0? But we know $A$⊂completion of $A$.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $I$ is an ideal of $R$, the completion $\hat{R}$ of $R$ at $I$ is the inverse limit of the system

$$R/I \leftarrow R/I^2 \leftarrow R/I^3 \leftarrow \cdots .$$

Yes, if $I = R$, then each of the rings $R/I^n$ is the zero ring, and $\hat{R} = 0$.

No, a ring is not necessarily a subring of its completion.  There *is* a canonical ring homomorphism $R\rightarrow \hat{R}$, but this homomorphism is injective if and only if $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}I^n = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for perfect elaborate answer!! I'm moved. Could I ask one more question regarding this one（actually, I hit upon this question because I was thinking this）? Hensel lemma holds in the zero ring ?

Comment: Often, we assume Henselian ring is local, but here, I don't assume local because Hensel lemma itself holds even in not-local ring.

Comment: Can you state precisely what you mean by Hensel's lemma?  I expect it will be meaningless or vacuously true for the zero ring, which does not have any maximal ideals.

Comment: Let A be a ring which is complete with respect to an ideal I, and let F ∈ A[w] be a polynomial. If for some m ≥ 1 we have F(0) ∈ Im and F′(0) ≡ 1 (mod I), then there is an element α ∈ Im with F(α) = 0, and the recursion w0=0, wn+1=wn−F(wn)forn≥0 converges to α. This is from Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves'.

Comment: Post a new question if you want, but you should be able to work out what this is saying for the zero ring.

Comment: I posted a question. Sorry to bother, but I'm looking forward to your answer.